# failed to sync configmap cache: timed out

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am creating a helm chart that contains many configmaps (20+) and everytime that I launch it the pod crashes and when I run `kubectl describe` it is full of warnings such as below:

```sh
Warning  FailedMount  24m                     kubelet, A-p51   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "bridge-dep" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  24m                     kubelet, A-p51   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "dashboard-hpa" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  24m                     kubelet, A-p51   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "dashboard-crb" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  24m                     kubelet, A-p51   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "bridge-http-svc" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
```

I checked the configmaps with the `kubectl get cm [cm-name] -o yaml` and they all exist and correct but I don't know why the pod crashes.

BTW, I am using Microk8s and K8s 1.16 for my development.

Comment: Hello @AVarf. Have you checked your RBAC rules for correct permissions?

Comment: Hi, I am creating SA, CR and CRB in that chart for my component but those have no problem and helm install doesn't give me an error and I can confirm that SA has been created.

Comment: Thanks @AVarf. Could you share your yaml configs for those RBAC rules?

Comment: @AVarf Did you figure out a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: It seems to be a transient issue. I was having all kinds of issues this morning, and after checking some system pods and deleting/recreating them the problem seemed to go away.

Comment: Damn, I've been unable to deploy for one whole week because of this issue. Unfortunately I don't have access to the cluster's administration to try to fix it :/

Comment: @AVarf Please post your answer if the issue has been resolved so that it would be helpful for other community members for reference.